# Finding index of matching array elements in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing, matching

Here is my task:

*Input: A list of numbers from the keyboard*

*Output: The second-smallest number in the list, along with its position in the list, with 1 being the position of the first number.*

Here is my code so far:

```
values = []
print "Enter a number: "
a = gets.chomp.to_i
values.push(a)

print "Enter another number: "
b = gets.chomp.to_i
values.push(b)

print "Enter another number: "
c = gets.chomp.to_i
values.push(c)

print "Enter a final number: "
d = gets.chomp.to_i
values.push(d)

new_values = values.sort

second_smallest = new_values[1]
puts "Second smallest number: #{second_smallest}"

if values.include? second_smallest
print "found matching element"
end
```

I am able to grab the second smallest element from a sorted copy and then check for that element in the original array. How can i grab the index of the matching element in the original array and print it to the user?

Sorry if it's simple I'm brand new to ruby

Comment: It is not hard to get the index of a value in an array. Arrays have an [index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-index) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby has a couple of handy methods on [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) and [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html), specifically [`Enumerator#with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) and [`Enumerable#min_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by). So you could do something like:

```
_, (value, position) = values.each.with_index(1).min_by(2) { |value, _| value }
puts "Second smallest number is #{value} found at position #{position}"
```

The `each` method returns an `Enumerator` if you don't pass it a block, which allows you to chain `with_index`, passing it's optional argument `offset` with `1`, so the first element is index 1 instead of index 0.

Now, the Enumerator is going to operate on a collection of `[value's element, index]` and we call `min_by` on that, telling it we want the 2 smallest values, and splitting the args out in the block parameters to `value` and ruby's "unused" variable `_`. So why did we call `with_index` if we ignore the index? Well, now `min_by` returns that `[value's element, index]` that has the 2 smallest `value's element` and we shunt the smallest back into the "unused" variable `_` and let ruby turn that next array, the second smallest, into 2 variables `value` and `position` which respectively contain the smallest element and the index (I tend to use position to mean something is 1 based and index to mean it's 0 based, but that's just a personal quirk). Then we can display those back out to the end user.

Do note however, you **do not** want to sort the `values` array prior to calling this. If you do you will always see the second smallest element is in position 2. (So in your example code, you want to work on `values` **not** `new_values`, and `new_values` goes away)

---

You can play around more with `min_by` and its return value if you want other variations, for instance, if you want only the third smallest value you could do:

```
*_, (value, position) = values.each.with_index(1).min_by(3) { |value, _| value }
```

The same thing, except for the splat operator `*` at the start, putting all but the last element into that "unused" variable. If you want the second and third smallest, you could do:

```
*_, (second_smallest_value, second_smallest_position), (third_smallest_value, third_smallest_position) = values.each.with_index(1).min_by(3) { |value, _| value }
```

to deconstruct and store in variables the last 2 return values of `min_by`. Or just

```
*_, second_smallest, third_smallest = values.each.with_index(1).min_by(3) { |value, _| value }
```

to store the arrays without deconstructing them into individual variables (since it's starting to become a mouthful)

Comment: What you have gets the smallest value, not the second smallest.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall fixed

Comment: If `values = [1,1,2]`, you obtain the value `1` at index `1`. That may well be what the OP is looking for, but `2` is most definitely the "second-smallest number". Also, consider using `.last` after `min_by`'s block.

Answer (score 1):

```
def second_smallest(arr)
  smallest = arr.min
  arr.each_with_index.reject { |n,_| n == smallest }.min_by(&:first)
end

second_smallest [3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5] #=> [2, 4]
second_smallest [1, 1, 1]             #=> nil
second_smallest []                    #=> nil
```

In the first example the second-smallest number is clearly `2`.